# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flush' with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've created a python method to print data to screen and in a file:

```
def printf(handler, string):

    print(string)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if handler is not None:
        handler.write(str(string))
        handler.write("\n")
```

The code works just fine when I'm running it in the virtual env. However, when I use the exe created using pyinstaller, I run into the error :

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flush'
```

The call to the flush method seems to cause the crash but I don't know how to solve this.
I did not find a solution after looking on the net.

How can the builtin `sys.stdout` be `None`?

Answer (score 2):

The Python docs say this:

> Under some conditions stdin, stdout and stderr as well as the original
> values __stdin__, __stdout__ and __stderr__ can be None. It is usually
> the case for Windows GUI apps that aren’t connected to a console and
> Python apps started with pythonw.

So, unless your exe file is running the terminal or Python's interactive mode then you will not have an std stream.

I'd do something like checking if the stream is there with some exception handling:

```
try:
   sys.stdout.flush()
except AttributeError:
   #Do something since you know you don't have an std stream
```

More here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=sys%20stdout#sys.stdout

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It gave me an hint on where the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I remove the option --noconsole when generating the exe with pyinstaller.